print a mutable nft using printV1 from @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata
how can I print an edition NFT that is mutable?
I'd like to be able to easily update metadata on printed nfts or nfts in a collection. But when I use printV1 it sets the edition to non mutable
const meta = await fetchMetadataFromSeeds(umi, {
        mint: publicKey(masterPublicKey),
    })

    // Generate transaction instructions for creating an edition NFT
    const mint = generateSigner(umi);
    const createNftInstructions = await printV1(umi, {
        masterTokenAccountOwner: treasury,
        masterEditionMint: nfts[nftName].publicKey,
        editionMint: mint,
        editionMintAuthority: treasury,
        editionTokenAccountOwner: publicKey(userPublicKey),
        updateAuthority: treasury.publicKey,
        editionNumber: BigInt(masterEdition.supply) + BigInt(1),
        tokenStandard: TokenStandard.NonFungible,
    }).getInstructions();

 // run logic

so when I call updateV1 I get an error
const meta= await fetchMetadataFromSeeds(umi, { mint: publicKey(editionPubKey) })

    const update = await updateV1(umi, {
        mint: publicKey(meta.publicKey),
        authority: treasury,
        data: { ...initialMetadataT },
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi)


Metaplex Token Metadata Editions are always immutable.
Metaplex Core Editions (The latest standard) can be mutable though. Maybe it's worth considering to use the new standard?

core github states: "Metaplex Core is currently undergoing audit. Use in production at your own risk."

The audit was finished in the meantime
